# Validate checkboxes in a button for Windows Phone 8 C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, checkbox

I have to select only 2 cakes to compare. I have a total of 6 checkboxes (cb1 to cb6) in which each checkbox is link to 1 cake, how do i validate that i have not selected less or more than 2 chekboxes in my back code for my button.

Currently im doing check by manually but it doesn't work. Is there a better way like doing for loop?

List LstCheckBox = new List();

```
    public class CheckBoxValue
    {
             public string cb1 {get;set;}
           public string cb2 {get;set;}

           public string cb3 {get;set;}

           public string cb4 {get;set;}
           public string cb5 {get;set;}
           public string cb6 {get;set;}
    public bool CurrentState{get;set;}
    }

 private void btnAddtoCompare_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {

 var lst = LstCheckBox.Where(m => m.CurrentState == true).ToList();

         if (lst.Count() == 2)
         {


             // everything is fine
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/UserMenu.xaml",
                   UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
         }
         else
         {
             // show your error message
             lblErrorMsg.Text = "Pls select 2 cakes ";
         }
```

}

xaml

```
private void cb1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

         bool CurrentState = true;
         cb1.IsChecked = CurrentState;

     }


private void cb2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         bool CurrentState = true;
         cb2.IsChecked = CurrentState;
     }
```

Comment: <CheckBox x:Name="cb1" Content="Select" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="31,351,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" Width="139" Height="73" ClickMode="Press" Click="cb1_Click"/>                        <CheckBox x:Name="cb2" Content="Select" HorizontalAlignment="Left"    Margin="187,432,0,0" Foreground="Black" Width="139" Height="73" ClickMode="Press" Click="cb2_Click"/>

Comment: My edit is not working for you ? If it is not then you have to understand it. because it is really simple. Just don't look for direct ans that you can copy Paste(actually you can do it with my code :)).

Answer (score 0):

Just make a List where CheckBoxValue is a class that basically save CheckBoxName and CurrentState. Like

```
// Fill it accordingly
List<CheckBoxValue> LstCheckBox = new List<CheckBoxValue>()

Public Class CheckBoxValue
{
 public string CheckBoxName {get;set;}
 public bool CurrentState{get;set;}
}
```

Save item to this on each CheckBox value changed event/property whatever. Now use `LINQ` for validating that list should have two items that have `CurrentState  = true`

```
    private void btnAddtoCompare_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      var lst = LstCheckBox.Where(m=> m.CurrentState == true).ToList();

       if(lst.Count() == 2)
       {
         // everything is fine
       }
       else
       {
         // show your error message
       }
    }
```

Hope it help you.

**Edit** :- I just don't want you to give a solution using Binding etc. This is the simplest workaround but give you clue to move forward.

```
// use this method to get the count of checked boxes; 
private int GetCountOfCheckedBoxes()
{
        List<bool?> lstOfCheckBoxesValues = new List<bool?>();

        lstOfCheckBoxesValues.Add(Cb1.IsChecked);
        lstOfCheckBoxesValues.Add(Cb2.IsChecked);
        lstOfCheckBoxesValues.Add(Cb3.IsChecked);
        // add your other CheckedBoxes similarly

        return   lstOfCheckBoxesValues.Where(m=> m == true).ToList().Count;
}

private void btnAddtoCompare_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var countCheckedBoxes = GetCountOfCheckedBoxes();

    if(countCheckedBoxes == 2)
    {
         // everything is fine
    }
    else
    {
         // show your error message
    }
}
```

// remove `CheckBoxValue` and other previous stuff that i suggested.

**Note :-** I right now using VS-2013 Windows Phone 8.1 SilverLight App template in which CheckBox IsChecked property is nullable type so if you will get error at `bool?` then just remove this `?`.

Comment: i tried it, but somehow i cant loop into the //everything is fine even when i checked 2 checkboxes. may i know why?

Comment: @Andrew i didn't get it. can you explain it more where are you having problem ?

Comment: for the public string CheckBoxName {get;set;} i replaced it all with my 6 checkboxes name, and when i run the project, i selected 2 checkboxes, it is suppose to go the next page but it still prompt me error.

Comment: the error is the label messgae i have put in the else.. if i check 2 checkbox, shouldn't it go into the if loop as the lst.count()== 2

Comment: @Andrew First put a break point on `if(lst.Count() == 2)` this line  and see is the count is exactly too or not. And can you show me your Xaml of checkboxes and How you handle their checking and unchecking. Basically when you uncheck/check then you should update the list accordingly e.g you have to set the CurrentState value corresponding to the checkbox. It is easy just think and made some effort. Or update your code i help you out.

Comment: i just updated. i think im wrong for handling the checkboxes.. could u guide me along, thanks.. ur help is appreciated as im new to this

Comment: @Andrew Give me 5-10 min. you are doing lots of wrong things. i give you a solution and link for some reading.

Comment: @Andrew check the edit. let me know and What you have under the xaml headline in your question actually that is not xaml at all. search what is xaml.

Answer (score 0):

I got the another method. Hope it helps you. Follow the below code to achieve your target.

```
public IEnumerable Cakes { get; set; }
public string Types { get; set; }
public bool IsSelectedRoles { get; set; }
```

And in your xaml,

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" Name="listBox" SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Types}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelectedRoles,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

And in your Cs file,

```
int count = 0;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<Items> list1;
        list1 = new List<Items>();
        list1.Add(new Items() { Types = "CheckBox1", IsSelectedRoles = false });
        list1.Add(new Items() { Types = "CheckBox2", IsSelectedRoles = false });
        list1.Add(new Items() { Types = "CheckBox3", IsSelectedRoles = false });
        list1.Add(new Items() { Types = "CheckBox4", IsSelectedRoles = false });
        list1.Add(new Items() { Types = "CheckBox5", IsSelectedRoles = false });
        list1.Add(new Items() { Types = "CheckBox6", IsSelectedRoles = false });
        this.listBox.ItemsSource = list1;
    }

    private void btnAddtoCompare_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Items _items;
        _items = new Items();
        _items.Cakes = listBox.ItemsSource;

        foreach (Items i in _items.Cakes)
        {
            if (i.IsSelectedRoles)
                count = count + 1;
        }
        if (count > 2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select only two items");
            count = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            // Navigate to Next page.
        }
        count = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;
private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var chekBox = (sender as CheckBox).IsChecked;
    if (chekBox==true)
    {
        count = count + 1;
    }
    if (count > 1)
    {
        (sender as CheckBox).IsChecked = false;
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: code only answers don't typically do well, can you explain this?